# How to force Port 25 to a VPN IP Address

Tags: vpn, cisco, port, cisco-vpn

I have a Cisco RV350 Router with a public IP, but the ISP does not allow port 25, and I have a VPN connection to Azure, so I have a public Azure IP address that allows port 25.

How do I forward all port 25 traffic through from my network to terminate on the Public IP in Azure?

Is there a such thing as Outbound Port Forwarding that I can tell it what IP address or better yet, what sub net to send the traffic to?

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to configure the server in Azure as an SMTP relay, and configure all clients/devices to use the internal ip address of the Azure server.

Comment: I'd rather do it with out creating a server if possible, I'd rather use my router to forward the request if possible.

Comment: There needs to be something to forward the traffic to. You could possibly create a dynamic NAT rule that forwards all traffic with a destination port of 25 to server at x.x x.x, although you would still need a server.